# Swift- dragging a custom made slider

Tags: swift, draggable, drag, uislider, touchesbegan

So I'm making a game and was previously using left and right buttons to move. Im thinking about changing it to a custom type of slider similar to this http://gyazo.com/05b6079862874a282ad14220e7267bd1 I'm not sure how to have it update the touches began so register you sliding your finger. What I have so far is this:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {


        for touch: AnyObject in touches {

            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.sliderBox{

                let move = touch.locationInNode(self)
                slider.position.x = move.x


        }
}
```

This gets the red dot to move to where I have touched, but I need to be able to have it like that and be able to slide when you hold it down. Thanks for taking the time to look at this.

Comment: There is an awesome tutorial here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/76433/how-to-make-a-custom-control-swift

Comment: Thank you for that. Ive been able to get it to work just by using override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) instead.

Answer (score 0):

fixed by changing override func touchesBegan to func touchesMoved

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches {

        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.slider{


            let move = touch.locationInNode(self)
            slider.position.x = move.x



        }
    }
}
```